# Formal grammar of first-order Peano arithmetic

Tags: first-order-logic, formal-languages, formal-grammar

I would like to write out the grammar of first-order Peano arithmetic in Backus-Naur Form. The alphabet I am using is $\{0,x,^*,(,),S,+,\times,<,=,\exists,\forall,\neg,\lor,\land\}$, where $x$ is a variable, $^*$ is a symbol used to index new variables, and $S$ is the successor function. Here is what I have so far.

```
<formula> ::= ( <formula> )
        | ¬ <formula> 
        | ( <term> <relation> <term> )
        | <quantifier> <variable> ( <formula> )
        | ( <formula> <connective> <formula> )

<term> ::= ( <term> )
        | <constant>
        | <variable>
        | S( <term> )
        | ( <term> <operation> <term> )

<constant> ::= 0
        | S( <constant> )
        | ( <constant> <operation> <constant> )

<variable> ::= x
        | <variable> *

<quantifier> ::= ∃ | ∀

<relation> ::= < | =

<operation> ::= + | ×

<connective> ::= ∨ | ∧
```

Is this the standard grammar for first-order PA?

Comment: It might not be 'the standard' one (if there's such), nevertheless seems pretty good.

Comment: At a quick look, one thing you might want to do is have more parenthesis. E.g. instead of `<formula> <connective> <formula>` use `(<formula> <connective> <formula>)` - strictly speaking I think you are supposed to have this.

Comment: @roundsquare Edited, thanks! Is it also necessary to have `¬ ( <formula> )`, or do `( <term> <relation> <term> )` and `( <formula> <connective> <formula> )` suffice to resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: @R.Burton formally, yes, I think you do. The parenthesis remove any ambiguity form the meaning of a statement (although, for humans, can make things _much_ harder to read :P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of the $(<term>)$ as an option for $<term>$ ... just use parentheses where needed elsewhere. Same for $(<formula>)$

Second, constant should just be $0$ .. as soon as you apply operations, it's a term.

Actually, most textbooks use 'atomic term' for either a constant or a variable, and 'complex term' for when you start using operations/functions.

So explicitly that would be:

$<term> ::= <atomicterm>
  | <complexterm>$

$<atomicterm> ::= <constant>
  | <variable>$

$<complexterm>::= S( <term> )
  | ( <term> <operation> <term> )$

$<constant> ::= 0$

or implicitly:

$<term> ::= <constant>
  | <variable>  
  | S( <term> )
  | ( <term> <operation> <term> )$

$<constant> ::= 0$

Comment: I was under the impression that every term is either a constant xor a variable?

Comment: @R.Burton I added a bit to my post ... hopefully that'll help